# How to get a value for this promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dictionary

people, I have a problem.
Within this model I make my sql query:

```
module.exports.contribId = (request, callback) => {
  connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM planilla_produccion_cantera WHERE id_planilla_produccion_cantera = ?',
    request,
    (err, result) => {
      var objPlanilla = {
        id: result[0].id_planilla_produccion_cantera,
        periodo: result[0].periodo
      };
      console.log('MY OBJ EN DAO: ', objPlanilla);
      callback(null, objPlanilla);
    }
  );
```

Then in my controller, I want to loope within a map to get the number of times of my array, and make the query select to my model the number of times of the array:

module.exports.contribId = (request, callback) => {
    const todo = [];

```
const mapAsync = (arr, fn) => Promise.all(arr.map(fn));

mapAsync(request, id =>
  contribModel.contribId(id, function(err, docs) {
    todo.push(docs); //here I need to push each value       
  })
);
console.log(todo); //here I need to print all the values of mapsync
```

}

but I can not get the array already completed. Could you help me?

Comment: Can you post your full file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In the model just return the promise.

```
  module.exports.contribId = (request) => {
  return connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM planilla_produccion_cantera WHERE anilla_produccion_cantera = ?',
    request
  );
}
```

In the controller collect the promises and use Promise.all api and then to parse the array o results.

```
module.exports.contribId = (request) => {
  const todo = [];

  const mapAsync = (arr, fn) => Promise.all(arr.map(fn));
  mapAsync(request, id => contribModel.contribId(id))
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('here you can parse all your todos')
    });
}
```